# Google cloud storage how to show deleted blob list

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to show that the list of blob deleted in bucket if version enabled in Google cloud storage. I am using the python code for these

```
 def bucketVersionHistory(self,bucket_name,serviceAccount):
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = serviceAccount #'<Service Account JSON file>'# Replace [BUCKET_NAME] with your actual bucket name
    
    # Create a client to access the Cloud Storage API
    client = storage.Client()
    # Get the bucket object
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket_name)
```

but above code is not show the delete blob list

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "version" parameter with a value of True, then you will have the deleted files in the list. After that you can check if the file is deleted using the "time_deleted" attribute

```
for blob in bucket.list_blobs(bucket_name, versions=True):
    if blob.time_deleted:
        ....
```